# angular throws 404 for *.bundle.js files when using a custom html5 base url

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, base-url

**Symptom**

After upgrading my Angular2 app to Angular `^4.1.2` and also the Angular CLI beta to `^1.0.3`, I got a 404 not found for my *.bundle.js files when running the app with `ng serve`. Note, that this symptom didn't occur in Angular2 and Angular CLI beta.

**Setup**

This issue only exists when I set the html5 base url to a custom url in `index.html`, e.g. `<base href="/some-path/">`. (I.e. if I set it to `<base href="/">`, the `*.bundle.js` files are found and my app works)

**Investigation**

The symptom occurs under the described circumstances, because the files are served on a root level by angular cli, no matter what the html5 base url is. So the real question is: **How can I tell Angular CLI to serve the *.bundle.js files on the specified base url OR tell angular to pick up the files on root?** I found an [issue request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/2727) that seems to deal with exactly this problem. Therefore, there is an option `--base-href` for the `ng serve` and `ng build` commands.

I tried using these options isolated as well as combined:

- `ng serve --base-href /assessment/`
- `ng serve --base-href /assessment/ --deploy-url /assessment/`

However, the symptom remained.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and looking for a while on StackOverflow and Github I find a solution working for me.

Try this: `$ng serve --base-href '/assessment/' --deploy-url '/'` it work on my project.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- don't add a custom route on `index.html` and locally develop on `/`
- use `ng build --base-href /assessment/` for building the angular app. This will create the route in the dist file and therefore work in prod.